# OnDrag does not work, but OnMouseDown works

Tags: unity

There is a code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragAndDropGame : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler
{

    Camera MainCamera;

    void Awake()
    {
        MainCamera = Camera.allCameras[0];
        Debug.Log(MainCamera);
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnBeginDrag");
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 newPos = MainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(eventData.position);
        newPos.z = 0;
        transform.position = newPos;
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnMouseDown");
    }
}
```

`OnMouseDown` fulfills, but the implementation of`IBeginDragHandler`, `IDragHandler` - not. What can be wrong?

Comment: Do you have an EventSystem set up in the scene with a Physics2DRaycaster and a 2D Collider set up on the sprite?

Comment: I have sprites on 3D plane in AR. I tryed all except 2D Collider.

Comment: You'll need the EventSystem, a PhysicsRaycaster, and a collider on the sprite for those methods to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IDragHandler` (and its associates) are only called for UI elements that are part of a canvas. And even then, only for UI components (Image, text, etc) and not 3D objects and colliders.

You are probably looking for [`OnMouseDrag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html).

Comment: I don't think these interfaces are limited to UI and hence canvases.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects/41392130#41392130) shows how to use these interfaces for both UI and 2D in game objects.

Answer (score 1):

You probably implemented `IDragHandler`, but forgot to implement  `IBeginDragHandler` and `IEndDragHandler`.

**All three must be implemented**, otherwise `OnDrag(PointerEVentData eventData)` will not be called for you.

For example, this will be ok:

```
public class Skins_TouchingArea_UI : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler{

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData){  Debug.Log("dragging"); }

    //required for OnDrag() to work
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {}

    //required for OnDrag() to work
    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this namespace:

```
using UnityEngine.UI
```

Comment: It did not help, but elements is sprites.